# Freemarker datamodel pollution

Tags: freemarker

I have started to user Freemarker to generate some output based on a datamodel. The issue I face is that I keep exposing methods in my datamodel for the sake of my output generation. So I have the feeling to "pollute" my datamodel for the sole sake of my Freemarker template.

Here is an example:
My datamodel, which is an interface in my case, provides this method (changed names and types for illustration):

```
Collection<MyPojo> getMyPojos();
```

In order to write the template the way I imagine it, I need to filter some of MyPojo based on some condition. I wanted first to do it in the template itself but it appeared quite complicated to manipulate lists within the template.
So I ended up adding other methods in my interface to cover the needs:

```
Collection<MyPojo> getAddedMyPojos();
Collection<MyPojo> getRemovedMyPojos();
```

Reading the Freemarker documentation, I didn't found a way to use some Fremarker API to provide more method to the template processor.
Is there any smarter way with Freemarker to achieve this goal? I would like to keep my interface clean with only the first method. Do I need to create a dedicated datamodel, extending my initial datamodel? Or to create a Map and to inject this one instead of my datamodel (and to populate it with the results of my methods)?

Thanks!

Comment: FreeMarker needs a view-model.  If the view is simplistic, then directly using the data-model can often suffice... but even then, many will argue you shouldn't.  If you're doing things like sorting, filtering, calculations, etc., then your view should definitely have a dedicated model: separate the concerns of storage and view.

Comment: Thanks Glenn for you comment. So in your opinion I should not provide the interface but rather the implementation, in which I can expose more methods if needed?

Comment: I would create a dedicated POJO that is used exclusively by your FreeMarker template.  Neither the data interface *or* its implementation should have any concerns or courtesy involving the view.  I know that doesn't sound very OOP, but data and view are very separate concerns.  You could have the "view POJO" take the data interface as a constructor argument, but I wouldn't make it aware of the data *implementation* however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by Glenn Lane it's better to isolate the code for Freemarker. So implementing a dedicated POJO